# How did I break inheritance?

Tags: c++, inheritance, oop

Refactored from [bug_report_view.cc](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/browser/views/bug_report_view.cc) and [bug_report_view.h](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/browser/views/bug_report_view.h), I extracted `send_report()`, `report_phishing()`, a few other smaller functions and `BugReport::Cleanup` into [bug_report.cc](http://codepad.org/pRBblPQQ) and [bug_report.h](http://codepad.org/5mHJXwaf) (my versions). Compiling now, I get:

> `[...]bug_report.cc:196: error: no matching function for call to ‘URLFetcher::URLFetcher(std::wstring&, URLFetcher::RequestType, BugReport::PostCleanup*)’
>   ../chrome/browser/net/url_fetcher.h:136:`
>
> `note: candidates are: URLFetcher::URLFetcher(const URLFetcher&)
>   ../chrome/browser/net/url_fetcher.h:82:`
>
> `note: URLFetcher::URLFetcher(const GURL&, URLFetcher::RequestType, URLFetcher::Delegate*)`

For some reason, `BugReport::PostCleanup` (in my version) isn't recognized as a subclass of URLFetcher::Delegate, but `BugReportView::PostCleanup` (in the first links) is. So where did I mess up? Thanks.

Comment: Can you make this question a little clearer? :-)

Comment: My bad. Links updated, and question expanded.

Comment: Can you add what compiler & OS you're building on?

Comment: Mac OS X, compiled using g++-4.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not the type of the PostCleanup class. The problem is the type of the first parameter to the URLFetcher class constructor. The constructor expects a GURL &, you are passing a `std::wstring` called `post_url`. You will need to perform some kind of conversion between the two. Possibly something like this would be appropriate:

```
GURL post_url(l10n_util::GetString(IDS_BUGREPORT_POST_URL));
URLFetcher* fetcher = new URLFetcher(post_url, URLFetcher::POST,
                                   new BugReport::PostCleanup);
```

In the code you have modified, the class has a GURL member which is initialised in the constructor, you have changed it to a variable referenced only in that one function, but changed the type.

Comment: Hah, wow. The last parameter drew my attention, and I totally missed that. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

At:

```
 URLFetcher* fetcher = new URLFetcher(post_url, URLFetcher::POST,
                                       new BugReport::PostCleanup);
```

it can't find an URLFetcher constructor thzat takes the parameters youn give it - the problem is presumably in url_fetcher.h, which you haven't shown.

BTW, there are a lot of other problems and bad practices exhibited in  your code - it would be a good idea to instigate a full code review ASAP.

Comment: Sure, that's where the problem is, but BugReport::PostCleanup is a subclass of URLFetcher::Delegate, so why doesn't it try URLFetcher::URLFetcher(const GURL&, URLFetcher::RequestType, URLFetcher::Delegate*)?

Answer (score 0):

First version used member variable post_url_ second just local variable post_url.
Please describe what is GURL type - it is typedef on std::wstring or something other.